# C# VirtualPathProvider Static-Pages

Tags: c#, virtualpathprovider, static-pages

I've got a virtual path provider (VPP) that serves simple aspx pages.
The problem lies when I introduce static references such as *.css, *.jpg files, etc ...

I noticed my VPP is capturing these requests. I don't want this to happen.
I want the normal System.Web.StaticFileHandler to handler these requests.

I've added the following in my web config:

```
    <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.css" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.js" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.jpg" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.gif" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

But my VPP still handles these requests.
Any ideas?

cheers in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess the VirtualPathProvider is invoked for every request. You'll have to override the [FileExists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.fileexists.aspx) method to tell the runtime whether the request is handled by the VirtualPathProvider or not.

Comment: Already doing that - slimmed down version:

        public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
        {
            if (virtualPath.EndsWith(".aspx"))
  return true;
            else 
                return false;
        }